# Perl regular expressions in system calls

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

The following Perl one-liner works as I expect it to; it strips my file of leading and trailing backspaces and replaces intermediate whitespaces with a single tab:

```
$ perl -pi -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file
```

What perplexes me is why I cannot get this to work via a `system` call from within my Perl code:

```
system "perl -pi -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+\$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file";  # '$' backslashed
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: A wild untested gues: double your \'s?

Comment: Already tried that, no success

Comment: What does `$?` (aka `$CHILD_ERROR`) say?

Comment: I've also ventured down the `system @args` road, but ran out of ideas

Comment: @Axeman : I don't have access to *nix at the moment, can't tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to launch another process for -i, but in general you should localize some of the global variables:

```
sub do_stuff {
  my $file = shift;
  local ($_, $., $ARGV, *ARGV);
  local ( $^I, @ARGV ) = ( '.bak', $file );

  while ( <> ) {
    s/..../..../;
    print;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
say "perl -pi -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+\$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file";
```

produces

```
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at -e line 1.
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at -e line 1.
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at -e line 1.
perl -pi -le 's/^s+//; s/s+$//; s#s+#   #g;' file
```

You want

```
system("perl -pi -le 's/^\\s+//; s/\\s+\$//; s#\\s+#\\t#g;' file");
```

Actually, why invoke the shell at all?

```
system('perl', '-i', '-ple' 's/^\\s+//; s/\\s+$//; s#\\s+#\\t#g;', 'file');
```

Comment: The `system @args` approach looks promising... will give it a whirl when I get my hands on a *nix box

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting that the backslashes get parsed first as a Perl double-quoted string, and then as a shell command.

The equivalent of the command line:

```
perl -pi -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file
```

in a Perl script is

```
system "perl -pi -le 's/^\\s+//; s/\\s+\$//; s#\\s+#\\t#g;' file"
```

Although it's silly to launch another copy of Perl just for this.  You're probably better off using a few more lines of code and doing it in the same process.

Comment: Y'know, I'm pretty sure I tried this earlier and it didn't work.

Comment: @Zaid, you probably missed a backslash somewhere.

Comment: The 'few-more-lines' option is what I ended up implementing... but couldn't figure out why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

runrig showed how you don't have to make a subprocess just to use -i.  Using -i internally is a bit weird, so there's two cleaner alternatives.  The first is to use [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aFile) which is fairly straightforward.

The other is to write to a temp file using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp) which is essentially what -i does.

```
my $tmp = File::Temp->new;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while(<$fh>) {
    s/.../.../;
    print $tmp $_;
}

my $tmpfile = $tmp->filename;
rename $tmpfile, $file or die "Can't rename $tmpfile to $file: $!";
```

Comment: If you are going to trouble yourself to doing all the heavy lifting yourself, you should make sure to close both handles and check their return results, errnoing if they fail. Otherwise I can’t see what’s cleaner about it.

Comment: @tchrist It's cleaner because it doesn't have to localize six magic variables and turn on obscure magic.  I can count on my fingers how many times my problems were solved by explicitly checking `close()`, but times I've been left scratching my head over code that uses magic variables would require a crowd.  Honestly either one is fine as long as it's put in a subroutine: `edit_file($file, $search, $replace);`  The important thing is the OP was asking the wrong question. :)

Comment: IIRC, filesystem being full is one example where checking `close()` is useful.

Comment: @DVK yes, checking close has it's uses.  I've weighed it's value and I'm just not obsessive about it.  Especially in sample code.  Especially especially when it has little to do with the OP's question. :P  Eventually autodie will just do it for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside double quotes `'` has *no* functional value. Your string will be edited by Perl. My tests show that you are losing the `\s` expressions. It's also interpolating the `'\t'`. tab--although that might not be so much the problem.

Here's `Data::Dumper`'s take:

```
$s = 'perl -pi -le \'s/^s+//; s/s+$//; s#s+#    #g;\' file';
```

Answer (score 0):

The double-quotes are interpreting everything.

try:

```
system "perl -pi -le 's/^\\s+//; s/\\s+\$//; s\#\\s+\#\\t\#g;' file";
```

Answer (score 0):

for Linux try

```
system q(perl -pi -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file); # comments here
```

for M$ windows:

```
system q(perl -pi -le "s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s#\s+#\t#g;" file); # comments here
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the situation that Larry gave us alternate quote characters for. We would like to use single quotes for system()s arg so that we don't have to figure out what needs backslashing, but we also need single quotes in the quoted string itself. So, alternate quote characters to the rescue!

```
system q(perl -p -le 's/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s#\s+#\t#g;' file);
```

Now you can copy/paste what works at the command line directly into your Perl source.